# Can we use dotenv vault for CRA?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv

Is the purpose of [dotenv-vault](https://github.com/dotenv-org/dotenv-vault) to hide away the environment variables?

How does this fit with create-react-app that use env variables prefixed with REACT_APP? I've read that when you run `npm run dev` CRA puts the variables prefixed with REACT_APP into the bundle in plain text. Does dotenv-vault help here somehow?